# Login field too short

Tags: users

I was looking at the SWEAVER module and managed to shorten the login field somehow in BARTIK theme. Now when I log out as ADMIN, it is not possible to Log in again because the LOGIN field is just too short to write in.

I wanted to use THEME DEVELOPER module to identify where the CSS for the region is, but I can't, because in ADMIN account the LOGIN field is not present.

The question is how to write something into this very short username and password fields? If I click in it the field gets highlighted, but when I write in it, nothing happens.

Unfortunately, I was trying to restore an older version of the database and restored a different one by mistake. Now im trying to restore the one I wanted but currently fighting with BACKUP AND MIGRATE module. Seems I just can't restore it because it's too big.

Comment: You stated some facts, now please ask a question. And the CSS length should not affect your ability to write in field. What exactly stops you from doing it?

Comment: :-) yes. The question is how to write something into this very short username and password fields? If I click in it the field gets highlighted, bud when I write in it, nothing happens...                                                            Unfortunately, I was trying to restore an older version of the database and restored a different one by mistake. Now im trying to restore the one I wanted but currently fighting with BACKUP AND MIGRATE module. Seems I just cant restore it cause its too big. Thanx for the comment about CSS that shouldnt affect the ability to write int he field.

Comment: You can write, just don't care you don't see it? Try. For DB, BaM creates normal SQL files, you can import it using any MySQL client. Or ask your admin to do it. Can't you?

Comment: Well, i tried it, but it is not possible to write in it. Now, I have to restore the DB before I try to solve this. But thanx!